# Different functional brachystochrone

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations, mathematical-physics

Until today I thought that $$ \int_0^b \sqrt{\frac{1+y'(x)^2}{2gy(x)}} dx$$ would be the only functional to derive the brachystochrone, but in the textbook Variational Methods in Mathematical Physics by Blanchard and Brünining I found the following integral:
$$ \int_0^b  \sqrt{\frac{1+y'(x)^2}{2gx}} dx $$

> Is this possible? If yes, how can one derive this equation?

I might have found something that could have to do with this but I am not sure whether it is the right reasoning, namely: $ds^2=\frac{dx^2+dy^2}{2x}$ and $ds^2=\frac{dx^2+dy^2}{2y}$ are both line elements for a 
[cycloidal metric](http://books.google.de/books?id=QxX2CX5OVMsC&pg=PA132&lpg=PA132&dq=Cycloidal%20metric&source=bl&ots=3J2lGUvbX0&sig=Y1MTDYNXJPwwN_s6-aCotp6U6Qc&hl=de&sa=X&ei=AlNEUeqGJsTbtAaI_YGQDA&ved=0CD8Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=Cycloidal%20metric&f=false).

Comment: Are you the real Lipschitz?

Comment: |cos x-cosy|<=|x-y| now convinced?